# How to excel file import to database in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, file

I have the same database table with excel in my hand.And I want to read the values ​​in this excel and save it in the database.And in the meantime excel would also like to read by providing control of whether the values ​​are empty or not.I want to do this with mvvm.If you click on the save button to check if the database is correct and I want to save.
**If you excel in the empty column etc. if you want to print it to datagrid.
If not, I want to print to the database**

Excel is:

```
  ID   NAME    CLASS

  12    JOHN    3  

  24    Alex    7
```

Database Table is:

```
ID    NAME    CLASS
```

I want to this excel is read and excel is insert to table.But I dont read and insert to table.I want to read excel and set datatable in excel.

I try to:

```
    //Excel Read Code

    Excel.Application app=new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook=app.workbooks.Open(fileName,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
    Excel.Worksheet sheet=workbook.Sheets[1];
    Excel.Range range=sheet.UsedRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`public void ReadExcel(string path){
 try
 {
 System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
 int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
 for (int r = 2; r <= rowCount; r++)
 INSERT INTO mytable (ID,NAME,CLASS)VALUES (dr[c - 1] = xlRange.Cells[r, c].Text, 
 xlRange.Cells[r,c+1].Text, xlRange.Cells[r,c+2].Text);
 }
 }
 }catch(Exception ex){throw ex;}
 `
```